# PHP logical : compare significance of element

Tags: php, roles, drupal-8

I want to know how can I implement something to compare the significance of the role of each user.

My 3 roles are : directeur_cr_, comptable_cr_ and salaries_cr_.

Where directeur_cr_ > comptable_cr_ > salaries_cr_

In my loop, I can get all user based on a certain value (in field_val). Then, I looking the role of each user.

what I want to do is this :

- If my user is directeur_cr_ , the loop ends.

  - else if my user is comptable_cr_ , the loops ends.
  - else if my  user is salaries_cr_, the loops ends.

The idea is that I want to keep the user with the highest role (here, directeur_cr_). If there's no directeur_cr_, look for the role under this one (so comptable_cr_). Same thing for the level under this one.

I have 3 users :

> 1. user 1 : comptable_cr_
> 2. user 2 : salaries_cr_
> 3. user 3 : directeur_cr_

My loop is actually working. I have this result :

> -- USER 1 --  directeur : false comptable : true
>
> -- User 2 -- directeur : false comptable : false salarié : true
>
> --User 3 --  directeur : true

What I'm looking for is this :

> -- User 3 --  directeur : true

no matter if there's other role (because I want the highest role available).

If directeur is not available, show comptable instead.

If comptable is not available, show salaries instead.

```
foreach($listeValuesDrupal2 as $valUnique){
  echo $valUnique;
  $users = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')
    ->loadByProperties(['field_val' => $valUnique]);
    dump($users); //show my user with $valUnique in field_val

  foreach ($users as $user){
    /*
        role : directeur_cr_ > comptable_cr_ > salaries_cr_
    */
    echo "<br/>------------------------- USER -------------------------<br/>";
    $user_has_role_directeur = $user && $user->hasRole('directeur_cr_'); //check if user has this role
    echo "directeur : "; dump($user_has_role_directeur);

    if(!$user_has_role_directeur){
      $user_has_role_comptable = $user && $user->hasRole('comptable_cr_');
      echo "comptable : ";  dump($user_has_role_comptable);//check if user has this role

      if(!$user_has_role_comptable){
        $user_has_role_salarie = $user && $user->hasRole('salaries_cr_');
        echo "salaries : "; dump($user_has_role_salarie);//check if user has this role
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: One way would be to simply reverse the tests, so start with the least important role and work towards the most important. Then if a user is all 3 the role assigned will be the most important one by the end of the tests

Comment: I would consider using a bitmask for the role. Users get assigned a role "number" that is based on the bits. Then you can use just a single line to compare a user with a function by doing something like: if (user_role $$ ROLE_DIRECTOR)..... It's a bit more complicated to set up, but not too bad. And it is extremely flexible.

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is just changing the display order ^^

Comment: @mrunion it's probably too complecated and I don't know what it is and how to implement that

Comment: THen simply look up `break;` in the PHP Manual

Comment: I tried this too, but if I break the loop after comptable_cr_, maybe I will miss my Director